# Force readmatrix to read into double array

Tags: matlab, csv, file

I've got an issue with matlab's new `readmatrix` function. For some reason, it has decided that my data file should be read as strings, and put into a cell array.
The data are not strings, they are doubles, and what's more, I wrote them to file using `writematrix`, albeit using `'WriteMode','append'`. The only tricky bit about it is that the rows aren't all the same length, but it handles other files with this same property perfectly fine, padding with nans.

How can I force `readmatrix` to recognise the data as doubles?

Output from `opts = detectImportOptions('fileName.csv')`:

```
opts = 

  DelimitedTextImportOptions with properties:

   Format Properties:
                    Delimiter: {','}
                   Whitespace: '\b\t '
                   LineEnding: {'\n'  '\r'  '\r\n'}
                 CommentStyle: {}
    ConsecutiveDelimitersRule: 'split'
        LeadingDelimitersRule: 'keep'
                EmptyLineRule: 'skip'
                     Encoding: 'UTF-8'

   Replacement Properties:
                  MissingRule: 'fill'
              ImportErrorRule: 'fill'
             ExtraColumnsRule: 'addvars'

   Variable Import Properties: Set types by name using setvartype
                VariableNames: {'x0_1'}
                VariableTypes: {'char'}
        SelectedVariableNames: {'x0_1'}
              VariableOptions: Show all 1 VariableOptions 
    Access VariableOptions sub-properties using setvaropts/getvaropts
        PreserveVariableNames: false

   Location Properties:
                    DataLines: [1 Inf]
            VariableNamesLine: 1
               RowNamesColumn: 0
            VariableUnitsLine: 0
     VariableDescriptionsLine: 0 
    To display a preview of the table, use preview
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant option here is `VariableTypes`. For some reason something in the file is triggering something in `readmatrix` to decide that it should be read in as `char`s. This can be fixed with `setvartype`.

```
opts = detectImportOptions('fileName.csv');
opts = setvartype(opts, 'x0_1', 'double');
data = readmatrix('fileName.csv',opts);
```

The string `x0_1` is the automatic variable name matlab sets in `VariableNames`. Assuming it is possible to read the data as doubles, this produce a matrix of doubles.